# What are the bare necessities for CSS snap scroll to work?

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap-points

I've been trying to implement a super simple horizontal snap scroll (as shown here: https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping ) yet I am consistently failing at that. I've probably searched through all the questions and answers here but none was of help.

My code is very simple, I am only declaring `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` on the parent and `scroll-snap-align: center;` on the child. And I am pretty sure it's not a browser issue (since I've tried it with many different browsers). What am I missing here? Or what do I not understand?

Here's my (not working) CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XyNNGY

**html:**

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Section 1</div>
  <div class='child two'>Section 2</div>
  <div class='child'>Section 3</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .parent {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  }

  .child {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: pink;
  }

  .two {
    background-color: crimson;
  }
```

Thanks a million already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you designate as the scroll snap container needs to be the one that the scrollbar is attached to. In your case, the parent element doesn't have a scrollbar — the scrollbar belongs to the viewport and the parent is extending past the size of the viewport without generating its own scrollbar. The `scroll-snap-type` property should therefore be applied to `body` (or `html`), not the parent:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

.two {
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Section 1</div>
  <div class='child two'>Section 2</div>
  <div class='child'>Section 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This snippet doesn't produce any scroll snapping behavior for me in the latest Chrome or Firefox (though it does in Safari)

Comment: @Luke Taylor: I haven't been in the loop with the spec for a few years. Something might've changed. Safari has the tendency to either be the first, or last, to be up to date on various features. By several years.

Comment: shouldn't it be linked to the html instead of to the body the "scroll-snap-type"?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.child {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>Section 1</div>
  <div class='child'>Section 2</div>
  <div class='child'>Section 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've accepted @BoltClock's answer for it helped me better to understand how scroll-snap works, but yours was also very helpful in reminding that you can make the parent scrollable (and thus snap-scrollable) by setting a max-height on it. So thanks a lot!